# Does terraform plan uses main.tf file?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Here's the snippet from my `main.tf` (thanks for reading it without a full viable example since it'd be pretty huge):

```
# main.tf
resource "foo" "example" {
   ...
   colors = ["BLUE"] # where "BLUE" is an enum with 3 possible values "BLUE", "RED", "GREEN"
}

# foo.go
func colorsSchema() *schema.Schema {
    return &schema.Schema{
        Type:     schema.TypeList,
        Required: true,
        MinItems: 1,
        Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
        ForceNew: true,
    }
}
```

After creating `main.tf` I run `terraform apply` and could see

```
"instances": [
  {
    "schema_version": 0,
    "attributes": {
      ...
      "colors": [
        "BLUE",
        "GREEN"
      ],
```

which is OK since the server does some optimizations and returns `["BLUE", "GREEN"]` (not just `["BLUE"]`) in this specific case.

However when I run `terraform plan` I can see that

```
  # confluentcloud_network.my-ccn must be replaced
-/+ resource "foo" "example" {
      ~ colors = [ # forces replacement
            "BLUE",
          - "GREEN",
        ]
```

That said, I've got the following code snippet and could see `fooRead` does set `colors` field correctly:

```
func fooResource() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        CreateContext: fooCreate,
        ReadContext:   fooRead,
...
func fooRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", d.Get("colors"))
```

I could see that the code indeed sets both colors correctly:

```
panic: [BLUE GREEN]
```

so how exactly does `terraform plan` works? It does call `GET` request for the specified `d.id`, what happens then?

It looks like it's using `main.tf` file too (instead of `terraform.tfstate`) since TF wants to revert to the state where `colors = ["BLUE"]` whereas both `terraform.tfstate & fooRead()` set it to `colors = ["BLUE", "GREEEN"]`

Comment: Yes, both the state file and the terraform files are used. The state file is basically only used to know which resources are currently provisioned (and to know which one to delete), the terraform file is used to determine the desired state. Terraform then refreshes all the resources and diffs it against the terraform file resulting in the plan.

Comment: @luk2302 what method does TF provider use to convert response and main.tf -> something it can use for diff comparison. Is there a way I could inject if BLUE -> set BLUE GREEN to avoid any diffs in terraform plan?

Comment: If your `read` returns two colors and the main.tf specifies just one then terraform knows they are different and tries to change them. You need to implement a proper `read` that does not just return arbitrary data but actually adheres to what a provider is supposed to do. You can `ignore_changes` the `colors` attribute within your `main.tf` or change your `read` to discard the "optimizations".

Comment: could you add your last comment as a reply and I'll mark it as accepted answer? @luk2302

Comment: is it correct that in the read func I've got access to both the state object and the actual state object so in theory we could do a req.state.SetAttribute (tf v3 logic) to work around this?